# Word(s) for "Workflow Optimizer"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Looking for word(s) that can describe a person's job title

> John's job is to go to companies evaluate their current process workflow and to implement changes to improve this workflow to be optimal . Since companies workflow need to change all the time to stay optimal John revisits his clients and analyze the workflow for improvements and develops systems to implement those changes.
>
> When John wife's ask him what his job is, he says he is a ...
>
> John put's on his resume and business card that his job title is ..

&

> Peter works on the production assembly line of the Tesla Model 3. His job is to analyze the production line, find improvements and implement those changes to the assembly line so that the assembly line produces more cars per hour.
>
> Peter's job title is ...

Words I thought of but don't fit

*Developer* - Closest I can think of but it means creating something when I want a word that is closer to convey the total of analyze,  optimize , change and improve together not just the creating part

*Reengineer* - This almost mean redoing it and it might not have to be redone if it is already optimal.

*Process Engineer* - The word engineer gets overused today and I want to try stay away from it

I am also not closed to the idea of it being a foreign language word(s)

Comment: A single word might not do; many job titles are two words, as indeed is one of your rejected possible answers. You _might_ want to consider editing your question to allow for longer answers.

Comment: Process Improvement Guru

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is **Business Process Consultant**.

However, a long time ago, such a person would be referred to as an **Efficiency Expert**. The term came in for a certain amount of derision, and fell out of use, but it could be used in a self-deprecating way that might appeal to some people. It couldn’t be used in written communication, but in conversation, it would be like psychologist calling himself *shrink*. It gets across the idea that the speaker is not afraid of the negative stereotypes of their profession, which *for the right type of speaker* can be a very strong statement.

There’s a charming novel called [The Efficiency Expert](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/3475) by Edgar Rice Burroughs (better known for *Tarzan of the Apes* and *John Carter of Mars*). The humor is a little dated, but some of the situations could have taken place yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

The term [Business Analyst](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_analyst) has been around for at least thirty years now, but there are still companies like [this one](https://www.liquidlogic.co.uk/careers/current-vacancies1/business-analysts-multiple-vacancies/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI1rDJrrz34QIVb7vtCh3HSQviEAAYASAAEgK4DfD_BwE) advertising vacancies with that title.

The point is that a Business Analyst can perform any task of this nature beginning with the evaluation of current procedures, carrying on to make recommendations for minor changes or going on to full Business Process Re-engineering.

There may be people whose job title is Business Process Engineer but, by background and training they will probably be Business Analysts.

Business Analysis is quite a good descrition of the work done by both people in the question although Peter might well be described as a Process Engineer since he is more likely to be a qualified mechanical or electrical engineer.

Answer (score 0):

Product Efficiency Manager is a job title of someone who makes production as ergonomic as possible. I believe it could work for you

Answer (score 0):

**Conveyor Belt**

I think John’s wife would appreciate the intelligibility and humour of an answer like this. I know mine would.

Not so good on a business card. But I’ve never had a business card, so I imagine any unintelligible meaningless nonsense would work there.